# why can't i access data in return statement but in console only?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, shopping-cart

i am trying to pass data (basically an array object) using Context in React js. I do receive the data at child node which i can see in console but when i try to render it dom i get

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

I have tried ideas found here and in google didn't get a way through. I have tried sending string objects in different project it works but when i try to do it my main problem i get this situation.

```
// Context.js

// imports...

export const ProductContext = React.createContext();

class ProductProvider extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      products: storeProducts, //storeProducts comes from external dataset
      available: "yes",
      drink: "Coca-Cola",
      type: "soft",
      price: 1.5
    };
    this.handleDetail = this.handleDetail.bind(this);
  }

  handleDetail(e) {
    console.log("hello from detail handler");
    // alert()
  }

  addToCart() {
    console.log("hello from addToCart");
  }

  render() {
    const providerData = {
      value: this.state,
      handleDetail: this.handleDetail()
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <ProductContext.Provider value={providerData}>
          {this.props.children}
        </ProductContext.Provider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const ProductConsumer = ProductContext.Consumer;

export { ProductConsumer, ProductProvider };
```

-

```
// list.js
// imports...
export default class ProductList extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    //console.log("FOR NOW ",this.state.products)
    return (
      <div>
        <ProductContext.Consumer>
          {data => {
            return data.value.products.map(
              //products contains data of products
              product => {
                return <Product key={product.id} product={product} />;
              }
            );
          }}
        </ProductContext.Consumer>
        <Product />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

-

```
// Product.js

// import....

export default class Product extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.product); //here i can see all the items present in
    dataset;
    return (
      <h1>Product name : {this.props.product.name} </h1>
      // i get error at this point
    );
  }
}
```

I think i am suppose to receive the data seen in console at return of render function. But i didn't find where i am making mistake

Comment: `i get error at this point` - what is the error?

Comment: offtopic OP, but you may want to look into using http://prettier.io/ -- it will help your format your react code properly

Comment: As @JaromandaX said, your problem can be more understood if you specify the error you've got.

Comment: one (or more) of members in the array `data.value.products` must be undefined

Comment: the error is TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined. But if i do console.log(data.value.product.id) i can see that id of the product is being fetched!!

Comment: @vins, just check the type of your data. maybe data is a string instead of an object.

Comment: @PulkitAggarwal thanks mate! my object looks like this PLEASE PROVIDE ME A FEEDBAck :      data.js :>>export const storeProducts  {
        id: 4,
        name: "",
        img: "",
        price:0,
        producer: "",
        description:"",
        inCart:false,
        count:0,
        total:0
    }export default  storeProducts

Comment: @vins I didn't get you, what you want

Comment: @PulkitAggarwal i am looking for fix for my the error i am facing. have not been able to fix it on my own so far. :(  I dont know whats confusing you ....do let me know what you are confused at ?

Comment: @vins Can you share the o/p of console.log or if this is critical for now you can try JSON.stringify and JSON.parse (just for hack if you want to run but it's not the correct way)

Answer (score 0):

After looking through the code, I find one confusing part.

Where there was a `<Product />` component without a passing a props.

try to change you code on list.js like this, hope this helps:

**list.js**

```
// imports...
export default class ProductList extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    //console.log("FOR NOW ",this.state.products)
    return (
      <div>
        <ProductContext.Consumer>
          {data => {
            return data.value.products.map(
              //products contains data of products
              product => {
                return <Product key={product.id} product={product} />;
              }
            );
          }}
        </ProductContext.Consumer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion ...didnt help i got this "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions"

Answer (score 0):

Its weird that it worked when id did like this in Productlist.js (Context.Consumer):

```
<ProductContext.Consumer>
                {data => {
                  return data.value.products.map
                  (
                      product => 
                    {
                      **return <Product key={product.id} product={product} name={product.name} price={product.price}/>**  //everything in same line ..don't know why 
                    }
                  )
                }}
              </ProductContext.Consumer>
```

Please feel free to  explain why this worked and not my previous ...basically didnot make much changes